# ggplot: changing the colors of specific points in scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

i am plotting biological age against chronological age over a 3 year period and im trying to plot a scatter plot that highlights only the points that crosses abline over the 3 year period. is that even possible? below are some of my data and the codes that i currently have to draw up the scatterplot.

```
head(mydata)

 SampleID       ba_baseline     ba_follow up ba_diff           age_baseline          age_followup age_diff
1      X3_0        59.03487        58.91077 -0.12409581               73.80               77.28    3.48
2      X5_0        58.96254        61.33064  2.36810749               82.71               85.45    2.74
3      X6_0        56.41316        52.37936 -4.03380246               73.14               76.95    3.81
4      X9_0        53.63238        56.31112  2.67873665               76.84               80.03    3.19

ggplot(mydata) + 
  geom_point(aes (x = mydata$age_baseline , y= mydata$ba_baseline),color="blue") + 
  geom_point (aes (x = mydata$age_followup, y = mydata$ba_followup),color="red") + 
  xlab("Age") + 
  ylab ("BA") +
  cleanup +
  geom_segment(data = mydata , aes(x=mydata$age_baseline, xend = mydata$age_followup, y=mydata$ba_baseline, yend = mydata$ba_followup), color=factor(ifelse(mydata$ba_diff < 0 ,"dark green", "blue"))) +
  geom_abline(intercept=0 , slope = 1 , linetype ="dashed", color="black")
```

im really new to R and i spent almost 2 days to come up with these few lines of codes so it would really be helpful if answers could be easier to apprehend.

thanks very much!

```
dput(mydata[1:5,]
structure(list(SampleID = structure(c(19L, 32L, 41L, 49L, 2L), .Label = c("", 
"X10_0", "X11_0", "X12_0", "X13_0", "X14_0", "X15_0", "X16_0", 
"X17_0", "X19_0", "X20_0", "X23_0", "X24_0", "X25_0", "X26_0", 
"X27_0", "X28_0", "X29_0", "X3_0", "X31_0", "X35_0", "X36_0", 
"X37_0", "X38_0", "X39_0", "X40_0", "X41_0", "X42_0", "X46_0", 
"X47_0", "X48_0", "X5_0", "X50_0", "X51_0", "X52_0", "X53_0", 
"X54_0", "X55_0", "X57_0", "X59_0", "X6_0", "X61_0", "X62_0", 
"X63_0", "X66_0", "X67_0", "X68_0", "X69_0", "X9_0"), class = "factor"), 
    ba_baseline = c(59.0348664, 58.96253611, 56.41316144, 
    53.63238385, 62.64326543), ba_followup = c(58.91077059, 
    61.3306436, 52.37935898, 56.3111205, 67.33817561), ba_diff = c(-0.12409581, 
    2.368107486, -4.033802462, 2.678736655, 4.694910184), age_baseline = c(73.8, 
    82.71, 73.14, 76.84, 75), age_followup = c(77.28, 
    85.45, 76.95, 80.03, 77.97), age_diff = c(3.48, 2.74, 3.81, 
    3.19, 2.97)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Not quite sure if I understand what is the result you are trying to achieve, but feels like you are looking for `geom_smooth()`? https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_smooth.html

Comment: One point: you don't need code like `mydata$age_baseline` as `age_baseline` will suffice. Question: do you mean you want to highlight **all** of the points above your 1:1 line or just the first point after your data crosses the line? Also, it helps if you provide an easy to copy-and-paste dataset that we can demonstrate with. For example, using `dput`.

Comment: @Lyngbakr Thanks for the pointer. I meant for all of the plots to be black, and only the plots that, at baseline lies above the abline and at followup lies beneath the abline (or vice versa) to be coloured. i've also put in the first 5 rows of my data using dput in the question

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, compare `age_*` and `baseline_*` beforehand and create a variable, like this:

```
mydata %<>%
  mutate(baseline_toggle = ifelse(ba_baseline/age_baseline > 1, 0, 1),
         followup_toggle = ifelse(ba_followup/age_followup > 1, 0, 1),)

ggplot(df) + 
  geom_point(aes (x = age_baseline , y = ba_baseline, color = baseline_toggle) + 
  geom_point (aes (x = age_followup, y = ba_followup, colour = followup_toggle )) + 
  xlab("Age") + 
  ylab ("BA") +
  geom_abline(intercept=0 , slope = 1 , linetype ="dashed", color="black")
```

You can then colour code them as you wish.

Comment: What function is %<>% supposed to be?

i am seeing "could not find function "%<>%"".

Comment: Forgot to mention — you need `magrittr`. That's the compound assignment pipe operator.